# Python iterate list datetime values

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using django-eventtools and have my occurrence data output as a tuple. I tried converting this to a list to be able to loop through it but I can't seem to get it to work. My querytest variable is my attempt and trying to iterate through the new list from the original tuple.

Here is my class and method where I am just calling the context to a django template:

```
class MyDashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
template_name = 'index2.html'
login_url = 'login/'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyDashboardView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['events'] = self.get_events_items_context()
    return context

def get_events_items_context(self):
context = {}

    query = list(RecurringAudits.objects.all().all_occurrences())
    querytest = [s for t in query for s in t]

    context['query'] = querytest

    return context
```

Here is my template code:

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
      {{ events.query }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The method all_occurrences outputs the data in generator format:

```
<generator object combine_occurrences at 0x7f07cee47258>
```

Here is what the query variable output looks like:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), {'title': 'Monthly Update Schedule'}), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), {'title': 'Monthly Update Schedule'}), (datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), {'title': 'Monthly Update Schedule'})]
```

Here is what the querytest output looks like:

```
[datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), {'title': 'Monthly Update Schedule'}, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), {'title': ' Monthly Update Schedule'}, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), {'title': 'Monthly Update Schedule'}]
```

My desired output(or something similar):

```
2018-3-31, 2018-3-31, Monthly Update Schedule, 2019-3-31, 2019-3-31, Monthly Update Schedule, 2020-3-31, 2020-3-31, Monthly Update Schedule
```

Comment: what is `query`? maybe this `[s for s in querylist]`

Comment: @Lemayzeur query is how I am passing the data to the django template. Also your suggestion just gives me the same output I am getting from the current queryset variable.

Comment: [s for t in **query** for s in querylist] <-------this query

Comment: @Lemayzeur I apologize I copied the code over wrong. I updated my question.

Comment: either you copied wrong yet again or, you have an issue there, where do you define querylist in that line  `[s for t in query for s in querylist]`. I see `querylist` nowhere in your code except here

Comment: @Lemayzeur I updated it again. It was supposed to be "t" not querylist. I was playing with different variable names and copied things over wrong.

Comment: can you show the output of `RecurringAudits.objects.all().all_occurrences()` as **tuple**, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170443/discussion-between-zorpho-and-lemayzeur).